# Receiving error messages when trying to open RStudio after installation on El Capitan

Tags: rstudio

Trying to run RStudio 1.0.153 on El Capitan, with R version 3.4.1 installed.

When I try to open Rstudio, it gives me the following error message and then a blank screen:

*Unexpected exception: invalid content of repeat range. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment....*
[Full error message from screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g83sT.png)

Running a diagnostic brings up the following output:

```
Using R script: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/bin/R

Attempting to launch R session...
    R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
    R_DOC_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
    R_INCLUDE_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
    R_SHARE_DIR=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share 
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf340:
    {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}:
```

{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}:\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\v
 iewkind0:\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx56
 69\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0:\f0\fs24 \cf0

```
/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/tools\:\cf0 
/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools}
HOME=/Users/user

03 Sep 2017 15:17:48 [rsession-user] ERROR Unexpected exception: Invalid content of repeat range.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(^|:){>>>HERE>>>\rtf1\ansi'.; LOGGED FROM: int rstudio::r::session::RReadConsole(const char *, CONSOLE_BUFFER_CHAR *, int, int) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/session/RSession.cpp:812

03 Sep 2017 15:17:48 [rsession-user] ERROR R SUICIDE: Unexpected exception: Invalid content of repeat range.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(^|:){>>>HERE>>>\rtf1\ansi'.; LOGGED FROM: void <anonymous namespace>::rSuicide(const std::string &) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2488
```

Tried reinstalling several times, as well as installing older versions of RStudio. But same error keeps popping up (apologies as I couldn't get the middle bit of the diagnostic output formatted properly)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.